# Break apart variable contents and load into array with php

Tags: php

This is what i have.

```
$number = 25880;
```

I need to break that up into individual lines in an array so i can read it like this

```
$numbers['1'] = 2
$numbers['2'] = 5
$numbers['3'] = 8
$numbers['4'] = 8
$numbers['5'] = 0
```

How do i do this in php?

Answer (score 9):

You can just use string functions as PHP will convert the number into a string before dealing with it.

```
$value = "0" . $number;
$numbers = str_split($value);
```

It doesn't do exactly what you want, as in PHP arrays are 0 indexed - but prepending the "0" will put the "real" contents where you asked for them.